# htaccess: one controller under root control all pages under all subdomains without redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I need a htaccess file under my root folder.

please see this photo url: [site structure](http://pix.ikeepstudying.com/JHRp9b)  (Sorry, I can not upload image to here)

I have lots of cities folder as my subdomains, but I do not wish every subdomain needs a separated admin,  I wish I can control them under the same admin page.

so if  I want :

> ny.example.com/news.php  ==> example.com/controller/ny/news ( or   example.com/controller.php?city=ny&section=news)

How can I write a htaccess file please ?

Answer (score 0):

In your root htaccess, add these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ controller/%1/news/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^controller/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ controller.php?city=$1&section=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: please try this :  http://test.ikeepstudying.com,  1. i dont want page to redirect to another link,  2. thought redirect, the  page still can not work well...